# Xamarin - If exist base class for BindingProperty?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have question:

If i have button and label - and I want to set style with `setter` `BackgroundColorProperty = Color.Black`. I tried to give to button in this way:

```
new Setter { Property = Label.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Black }
```

And Its work.

So question - if exist base class or something which I can to use in the way:

```
new Setter { Property = BASECLASS.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Black }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class of every visual element is `VisualElement`.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement/

If you use Resharper, it would tell you that you can use the base class in this case :)

[image]